# List of char* in C++

Tags: c++, list, char

I have a function that prints all the clients connected at a server.I want to put all clients in a list of char ( list lst ) because i need them in other functions.When i want to iterate over the list lst and print the elements appears something like " $@ ".I don't understand why.
These are the functions:

```
void get_clients_list(){
    int dim,i = 0,n;
    char buff[255];

    bzero(buff,sizeof(buff));

    recv(srv_fd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);

    dim = atoi(buff);

    printf("\t%d clients available:", dim);
    printf("\n");

    while(i < dim){
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        recv(srv_fd, buff, sizeof(buff),0);
        if(n < 0){
            error("ERROR reading from socket");
        }
        lst.push_back(buff);
        printf("\t\t%s", buff);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

And here is how i iterate over the list lst:

```
get_clients_list();
iter = lst.begin(); 
while(iter != lst.end()) {
    iter ++;
    printf("clients:");
    printf("%s \n",iter);
}
```

Why it doesn't print the clients and only appears some hieroglyphs?

Comment: why not make the `char*` into `string`? and use `cout` instead of `printf`? The garbage you are seeing is bad juju.

Comment: You are attempting to print an iterator. That is not a string. Use more C++ and less C!

Comment: Please also provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a pointer to a local variable here:

```
lst.push_back(buff);
```

This is undefined behavior. As well you need to use `*iter` in order to obtain the contents of the iterator:

```
printf("%s \n",*iter);
```

Since you are using C++ it would be much simpler and less error prone to use `std::string` and `iostream` library. Sticking as closely to the code you have here is a small example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buff[] = "hello, world" ;
    std::vector<std::string> lst;

    lst.push_back( buff ) ;

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = lst.begin() ;
    // In C++11 could be replaced with
    //auto iter = lst.begin() ;

    while( iter != lst.end() )
    {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl ;
        ++iter ;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use list<string> lst,how can I compare with an element from another list of char?If I use strcmp it doesn't work.

Comment: probably should be `std::vector`, not `std::list`.  Nowhere in the question do I see any mention of a doubly-linked list.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point, I think my brain saw `lst` and just did a replace with `std::list` but from the code given `std::vector` makes more sense, although it is not clear what `lst` is. Example amended.